# Meaning of jar.enabled=false in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I've seen in a build.gradle file the following setting:

```
jar.enabled = false
```

What does that line do?

Sorry but I just couldn't find it on Google.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html section 67.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAR stands for Java ARchive. JAR is the only archive format that is cross-platform and the only format that handles audio and image files as well as class files.

When `jar.enabled` is set to `true` it creates a JAR of your application in `build/libs/`.